# Storing long hexadecimal value in Ethereum/Quorum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, quorum

We're operating a private blockchain using Quorum for a research project.  We're storing large amounts of data in transactions as strings.  We've hit the size limit (we think, open to thoughts there too) and have been able to span the data across multiple transactions, etc., so the ability to store everything we want isn't really the issue.

We are storing just a long string of hexadecimal characters, and what we're wondering is if instead of string, we could store them more efficiently as something else and maybe stretch the data field out by switching from string to a different datatype specialized for hexadecimal.

Any ideas?  Like I said, we're operational, but I've bene having a hard time figuring out whether this is possible, or even a good idea.  The hexadecimal "0xab34ef6......26ef" would not resolve to a number or anything (its a string of independent characters that just happen to be hex.

Thanks and take care,

Mark

Comment: I will gladly accept an answer that says this is a dumb idea and it won't work :)

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I am also trying to store a set of data. I've been able to  create large `bytes` arrays up to `new bytes(135000)`. After roughly that number I start to see gas limits and other issues

Comment: We ran into similar issues.  We're at the point that we'll require multiple transactions at any rate, so it't actually not a huge deal to just spread them across as many as it needs once we're doing it at all... not proud of it, but time to move on to new issues :)